# Fetch data to get a line chart using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, chart.js

I have a line chart, which shows values vs months. I want to fetch these values from mysql and place it in the right order,
My DB looks like:

```
month | cpi | team
jan     1.0    A
jan     1.1    B
feb     1.2    A
feb     1.3    B...so on
```

so far I have the connection to the db working and, I've tried several ways but always end up in the same point, so how to bring this info from mysql? on my last attempt I've place as a label the january field only as you can see. here the sample of the chart code:

```
 *<div class="container"></div>
    <script>
        function createConfig(gridlines, title) {
            return {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July','August','September','October','November','December'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Density',
                        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.orange,
                        borderColor: window.chartColors.orange,
                        data: [<?PHP echo $CPI; ?>, 0.00, 1.05, 4.00, 1.15, 1.24, 2.00],
                        fill: false,
                    },*
};
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        var container = document.querySelector('.container');

        [ {
            title: 'CPI Charts',
            gridLines: {
                display: true,
                drawBorder: true,
                drawOnChartArea: true,
                drawTicks: false,
            }
        }].forEach(function(details) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.classList.add('chart-container');

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            div.appendChild(canvas);
            container.appendChild(div);

            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var config = createConfig(details.gridLines, details.title);
            new Chart(ctx, config);
        });
    };
```

Thank You!